# AngularJS $http factory is not working

Tags: angularjs

I guess the `$http.get` part is not working .
Here is my code :

```
.controller('home', function($scope, request){
            $scope.list = request.get(baseUrl);
    })
.factory('request', function($http){
        var get = function(url){
            $http.get(url).success(function(data){
                console.log(data); 
                return data; //returns nothing
            });
        }

        return {
            get : get
        }
    });
```

Comment: Define the success callback function like this `function(data, status, headers, config)` and then print each argument to the console and let's know the output.

Comment: @bmleite the success function actually isn't executing I mean $http.get isn't working

Comment: Why do you say "$http.get isn't working"? Do you see any error in the console?

Comment: nope i tried printing console.log("test")
inside the success function but it didn't print anything

Comment: And if you replace `success(` by `error(` is anything printed?

Comment: Is `baseUrl` defined in your controller somewhere?

Comment: F12 in chrome to check if there is a javascript ERROR before doing anything else.The code is working,the server is just not responding with a 2XX code so it triggers an err in the promise.

Comment: $http.get is an async function, you need to return a promise not the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, your function doesn't return anything at all - if I were to call request.get(), it would return undefined. You want something like

```
.controller('home', function($scope, request){
    request.get(baseUrl).then(function(data){ // I prefer then and catch semantics
        $scope.list = data;                   // as they're standard promises form
    })['catch'](function (err){console.log(err)});
})
.factory('request', function($http){
    var get = function(url){
        return $http.get(url).then(function(data){
            console.log(data); 
            return data; 
        });
    }
    return {
        get : get
    }
});
```

Although this is unnecessary obfuscation for a simple case (i'd just put the `$http.get().then().catch()` stuff in the controller instead of a factory.

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
.factory('request', function($http){
    var get = function(url){
        return $http.get(url).success(function(data){
            return data;
        });
    }

    return {
        get : get
    }
});
```

Update your controller.

```
request.get(url).then(function (data) {

  $scope.data = data;

}, function (response) {
     // handle error
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/eWXckgiwPNCGMlP0LQyk?p=preview

Comment: The controller is wrong too:
`request.get(baseUrl).then ( function ( data ) { $scope.list = data });`
Which you did in the plunker, I guess I should have looked at that first... sorry.